# I'm trying to find a marginal distribution for a function and I need to solve the integral bellow.

Tags: integration, marginal-distribution

I have arrived at the following integral: $$\int_y^\infty \frac{e^{-x/2}}{2x^2}$$ The limits I'm not so certain, but the function is correct. I have tried integration by parts but I arrived at a more complicated function. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I have $f_X(x)$ with $exp(\frac{1}{2})$ distribution and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ with $Uc[0, x^2]$ distribution. I found the joint distribution by multiplying both and I wanted to find $f_Y(y)$ so I could calculate $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $Var(X)$, $Var(Y)$ and $Cov(X,Y)$. But, by looking at the answer to the integral I think I took a wrong turn somewhere...

Comment: there is no closed form for this integral

Comment: What was the joint density?

Comment: @StubbornAtom edited the question to include it. I believe I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Indeed. Write down the densities with full support (use indicator functions) and then proceed. If $Y$ given $X=x$ has distribution $U(0,x^2)$, then $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\mathbf1_{0<y<x^2}$. (so what is the range of $x$?) Also, you don't need to find marginal of $Y$ to find its mean, variance or even the covariance.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The range of x is not given. How can I find $Y$ variance without finding its pdf?

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_y^\infty\frac{e^{-x/2}}{2x^2}dx=\frac 14\int_{y/2}^\infty u^{-2}e^{-u}du$$
Now note that the incomplete gamma function is defined as:
$$\Gamma(s,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
So we can say:
$$I=\frac 14\Gamma\left(-1,\frac y2\right)$$

Comment: Here is the wiki for the incomplete gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function